# Can I ask to start my postdoc remotely during an interview? (Postdoc is in the UK and I live in another country)

Tags: postdocs, job-search, job, united-kingdom, interview

So, I was invited for an interview in England, which is currently on a national lockdown at least until January. They send the invitation email when the lockdown was a regional thing, but they confirmed the details during the national lockdown.

Personally, it would be great for me if I start working remotely for a month or two, I need to sort a lot of things in my home country. Since the country is on a lockdown, there's a high chance that they might bring it up. But if they don't, can I mention it? (and how can I do it?) I'm scared that it might play against me.

Comment: I would suggest that - unless they bring it up themselves - you don't need to mention this at interview stage. Wait until you've been offered the job, and then discuss it as part of the 'when can you start' conversation.

Comment: @avid But of course, the OP *will* have to bring up the "when can I start" question.  Otherwise, it would seem odd given that (apparently) there was no information available on that.  (I mean, everyone is looking for a position around a specific time, right?)  Then it would seem odd to not voice that they might want to start a bit later and/or remotely.

Comment: I wouldn't be at all surprised if the university *insisted* on it, actually: certainly we're all working remotely (albeit at a somewhat shorter distance) anyway.

Comment: @user3482749 Yes, I think that the panel will bring the issue. It is like you said, everyone is working remotely, now.

Comment: The UK may have just a few more problems with international recruits than a temporary lockdown, some of which I guess even universities still have to get used to.

Comment: @Mark can you please explain?

Comment: @U.User Related to brexit which just became effective last week; EU citizens need a visa to get to and work in the UK, there are different types of visas, application procedures, and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't be concerned. This is a common concern these days, so I'm sure they will understand.  It might be that they tell you that it is not possible for legal reasons.  It might however even be that they are happy to know you are willing/interested to work remotely for a while, since under the current circumstances, there might be significant difficulties/delays in getting you into the country in a timely fashion (depending also on your passport, and where you travel from).

Regarding as to how to bring it up, you should do so as a question - like "Would it be possible to work for a month or two remotely, given that it will be difficult to relocate (and other reasons)", but it is certainly good to present it in a way which will make it also look favorable to them, i.e. "give us more time for the relevant paperwork".

Of course, this all also depends *when* the position is actually meant to start. I assume it is soon, so chances are high that restrictions are still in place at that point.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I am aware of the legal reason complications. Actually, I expected that they might cancel the interview due to the current situation there. But, they did go through process regardless of the lockdown, so I don't think it's reasonable to invite international candidates for an interview and expect them to wait until things cool down, right? Keep mind that the daily cases are still increasing even with a national lockdown. Also, there is no information about the starting date.

Comment: @U.User if you have no information about the starting date, how can you say you want to start 1-2 months later?  This will sound completely pointless!  Ask about the starting date first, and then have an answer ready depending on what they say!

Comment: Yes, of course! I am not planning to ask the question like that. I'll mention it when I get more information during the interview.